# Open Layers: How to add additional layer group in layers switcher panel?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers, layer

How to add additional layer group in layers switcher panel.
I want to create another layer group name as "Base Layer" and "Overlays". Is there any API to customize this part in Layers Switcher?

Comment: See possible duplicates: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/1086 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018958/how-to-add-2-layers-in-a-group

Comment: Thank You for your answer, but I would like to avoid from integration, because my page is very functional and a little more JS code loading is already much for this page. I thought that OpenLayers could have, but I hadn't find it. Anyway, Thank you.